# Getting strings from arraylist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

My code is making arraylist from sqlite database, like this.

example of arraylist:
[image: example of arraylist]

So for example, if users wants to see everyone from my list with address "example2", how I do it in code? If it helps, im printing the results to gridview. Im able to print EVERY data there, but I want it to be filterable by user choice.

So far I've made a model-class which have getters and setters for all the information. I also have an adapter which prints wanted data to my objects in my MainActivity. The thing is that I want to filter the data before the data is shown, so I think it has to be made in my adapter. But i've no idea how?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You provided no code, so here is a general answer: Query for entries with address "example2" with a SQL-"select" statement, so you only get matching entries, instead of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it in SQL then it goes as `Select * from arraylist where address = "example2"`. Please mention which language you want to code in?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are trying to gather all data from your users database into a list:

```
 public static List<User> getUsers() {
            List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
            DataSource ds = MyDataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource();
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                con = open(con, ds);
                String SQL = "SELECT id,name,address from YOUR DATA TABLE;
                stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int i = rs.getInt("id");
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    String address = rs.getString("address");
                    User us = new Location(i,name,address);
                    locs.add(loc);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                close(stmt, con, rs);
            }
            return res;
        }
```

This two methods are for opening and closing your connection with your database:

```
public static Connection open(Connection con, DataSource ds)
                    throws SQLException {
                try {
                    con = ds.getConnection();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (con == null) {
                    throw new SQLException("cannot connect to database!");
                }
                return con;
            }

public static void close(PreparedStatement preparedStatement,
                    Connection con, ResultSet rs) {
                try {
                    if (rs != null)
                        rs.close();
                    if (preparedStatement != null)
                        preparedStatement.close();
                    if (con != null)
                        con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good idea to filter data from code, but you can do it in the sql query.
Like this:

```
SELECT id, name, address FROM table WHERE address = 'example2'
```